# Ext combobox select after store reload doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here is my combobox configuration

```
{
    xtype : 'combo',
    fieldLabel : 'Select Field',
    displayField : 'field_name',
    valueField : 'field_id',
    id : 'fields_combo_id',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
         proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:eyefind.config.DATA_RETRIEVAL, method:'GET'}),
         baseParams: { subject: 'fields' },
         root: 'data',
         id: 'field_id', 
         fields: ['field_name'],
         autoload: true
     }),

    labelStyle : 'font-weight:bold; width:100px',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    clearFilterOnReset : false,
    mode : 'local'
 }
```

I load the store in an external function in this way:

```
        .....
        var comboFields = Ext.getCmp('fields_combo_id');
        comboFields.store.load(); 
        comboFields.setValue(selectedFieldId);
        .....
```

And so far selectedFieldId has been set but in the visible part I see a value instead of displayText, the store looks fine and I have the `value:displayValue` pair properly set there.

Do I miss something or do I have to use some other functionality for this part?

My version of [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29) is 3.2.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set `valuefield : 'field_id'`, but there is no `field_id` in store's `fields`,

```
{
    xtype : 'combo',
    fieldLabel : 'Select Field',
    displayField : 'field_name',
    valueField : 'field_id', //This 'field_id' must be in store fields too.
    id : 'fields_combo_id',
    store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({url:eyefind.config.DATA_RETRIEVAL, method:'GET'}),
        baseParams: { subject: 'fields' },
        root: 'data',
        id: 'field_id', //This id is just for the store, not the record data.
        fields: ['field_id','field_name'], // here, i add `field_id`
        autoload: true // This should be autoLoad, remember JavaScript is case sensitive.
    }),

    labelStyle : 'font-weight:bold; width:100px',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    clearFilterOnReset : false,
    mode : 'local'
}
```

And also, why do you set `autoLoad : true` if you load it again in your external function?

EDIT

When I run `comboFields.setValue(id);`, in which my id is assign to one of the field id, it works, and I see displayfield on my combo (no need to dropdown first). But, if, in your case, your combo item has been highlighted, I guess it's because of the version. Unfortunately
I tested it in Ext 3.3.0.

Comment: agree about aoutoLoad, also the filed_id has missing that is correct, but I make all like this and again in combobox I see value not displayValue, but when I click and drop down to see the list my displayValues has been highlighted, what is good but still not 100% :(

Comment: Yea besically it works now, just not in firts case whe I open that window with combobox, once when I reopen it it works as expected, so initially it highlight and put value as displayValue, after close/open it works as expected, thanks in any case!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
var selectedFieldValue = Ext.getCmp('fields_combo_id').getRawValue();
var selectedFieldId    = Ext.getCmp('fields_combo_id').getValue();
comboFields.setValue(selectedFieldId,selectedFieldValue);
```

Comment: I already try that, but that wasn't helpfull at all, it returns me same Value in both cases.

Comment: @vaske : If you don't want valuefield in post then you can use `comboFields.setRawValue('value');`